# How do breakaway helmet accessory mounts work?

Tags: helmets

I've seen it said that when mounting things such as a light or camera on your helmet you want a breakaway mount so that in the event of a crash the helmet slides along the ground rather than snagging on it.  What is it about these mounts that lets them break away?

Comment: Designed-in weakness.

Comment: Fragile plastic?  Slender straps?  Scoring a piece where it's supposed to give way?

Comment: Whatever it takes.

Comment: Theres a bit more to it than just a fragile clamp.  The item has to break away safely on a side impact as well as a direct frontal impact.  A helmet-mounted camera is what exacerbated Michael Schumacher's skiing accident, by focussing the impact not dissipating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My [Light and Motion helmet light](http://www.lightandmotion.com/choose-your-light/vis-pro) has two built-in weaknesses that seem designed to fail on impact, tearing the light away from my helmet and not allowing any impact torque to transmit through to my neck:

- The light and battery plastic mounts (the plastic-to-plastic connections) are intentionally weak and will pull away with very little force
- The velcro that connects the mounts to the helmets isn't very strong and would tear if there was greater lateral force on them

I haven't tested the breakaways in an accident (and don't hope to) but I can say that the light and battery have released when I've hit them on low ceilings in my garage, to my chagrin.